# Fixed size QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a QMdiSubWindow, that contains a QTabWidget which contains QGraphicsView inside a widget with a QHBoxLayout. The sub window is in an mdi area in my main window. My objective is to have a fixed size for QGraphicScene, depending upon the paper size i am using.
The view should then either conform to the same size as the scene, showing no scroll bars if this area can fit the total available mdi area, resizing the subwindow as well, or should resize to fill the available area resizing the sub window too, and should show scroll bars to navigate to the remaining space.

My current approach revolves around resizing the mdi subwindow first, then making a call to resize the current active widget in the window's QTabWidget. 
This is all done as per musicamante's implementation. 
The current widget chooses the min value between the parent(QStackedWidget)'s parent(QTabWidget)'s parent (QMdiSubWindow)'s rect (as it is resized first) and the dimensions of the QGraphicsScene which is updated when I set the dimensions.

-> Set QGraphicsScene dimensions from user input

-> Resize sub window

-> Resize QGraphicsView

I use the same logic, on my program, which fails to show scroll bars at all and the view expands to fit the QGraphicsScene despite being told to be the size of the sub window instead (sub window is of correct size), and the following example, where they do show as necessary but are clipped off partially.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
paperSizes = {
    "A0": {
        "72": [2384, 3370],
        "96": [3179, 4494],
        "150": [4967, 7022],
        "300": [9933, 14043]
    },
    "A1": {
        "72": [1684, 2384],
        "96": [2245, 3179],
        "150": [3508, 4967],
        "300": [7016, 9933]
    },
    "A2": {
        "72": [1191, 1684],
        "96": [1587, 2245],
        "150": [2480, 3508],
        "300": [4960, 7016]
    },
    "A3": {
        "72": [842, 1191],
        "96": [1123, 1587],
        "150": [1754, 2480],
        "300": [3508, 4960]
    },
    "A4": {
        "72": [595, 842],
        "96": [794, 1123],
        "150": [1240, 1754],
        "300": [2480, 3508]
    }
}
class canvas(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, size= 'A4', ppi= '72'):
        super(canvas, self).__init__(parent)
        self._ppi = ppi
        self._canvasSize = size 
        self.painter = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()        
        self.painter.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.white))

        self.view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.painter)
        # self.view.setMinimumSize(595, 842)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.view, stretch = 1, alignment= QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.painter.setSceneRect(0, 0, *paperSizes[self.canvasSize][self.ppi])

    def resizeView(self, w, h):
        self.painter.setSceneRect(0, 0, w, h)
        self.adjustView()

    def adjustView(self):
        self.view.setSceneRect(0, 0, self.painter.sceneRect().width() - self.view.frameWidth() * 2, 
            self.painter.sceneRect().height())
        # give the view some time to adjust itself
        QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
        width = self.painter.sceneRect().width() + self.view.frameWidth()*2
        if self.view.verticalScrollBar().isVisible():
            width += self.style().pixelMetric(QtWidgets.QStyle.PM_ScrollBarExtent)
        height = self.painter.sceneRect().height() + self.view.frameWidth()*2
        if self.view.verticalScrollBar().isVisible():
            height += self.style().pixelMetric(QtWidgets.QStyle.PM_ScrollBarExtent)

        self.view.setFixedWidth(min(self.parent().rect().width() - self.view.frameWidth()*2, width))
        self.view.setFixedHeight(min(self.parent().rect().height()- self.view.frameWidth()*2, height))
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.adjustView()

    def setCanvasSize(self, size):
        self.canvasSize = size

    def setCanvasPPI(self, ppi):
        self.ppi = ppi

    @property
    def canvasSize(self):
        return self._canvasSize
    @property
    def ppi(self):
        return self._ppi

    @canvasSize.setter
    def canvasSize(self, size):
        self._canvasSize = size
        if self.painter:
            self.resizeView(*paperSizes[self.canvasSize][self.ppi])

    @ppi.setter
    def ppi(self, ppi):
        self._ppi = ppi
        if self.painter:
            self.resizeView(*paperSizes[self.canvasSize][self.ppi])

    @property
    def dimensions(self):
        #returns the dimension of the current scene
        return self.painter.sceneRect().width(), self.painter.sceneRect().height()

class AppDemo(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AppDemo, self).__init__()
        self.centralwidget = canvas(self)
        width, height = paperSizes['A4']['72']
        wsetter = min(1800, width - self.centralwidget.view.frameWidth()*2)
        hsetter = min(900, height - self.centralwidget.view.frameWidth()*2)
        self.setFixedSize(wsetter, hsetter)
        self.centralwidget.resizeView(width, height)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.resizer)
        self.show()

    def resizer(self, point):
        width, height = paperSizes['A0']['300']
        wsetter = min(1800, width - self.centralwidget.view.frameWidth()*2)
        hsetter = min(900, height - self.centralwidget.view.frameWidth()*2)
        self.setFixedSize(wsetter, hsetter)
        self.centralWidget().resizeView(width, height)
def main():
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = AppDemo()
    w.setWindowTitle('AppDemo')
    w.centralwidget.resizeView(*paperSizes['A0']['72'])
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: A stretch always resizes according to the available size, which is computed using the other sibling widgets size policies. Right now, according to your code, you're only changing the scene rect for the view, can't you set a fixed width to the graphics view accordingly?

Comment: so set a fixed width along with setting the scene rect?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Setting the view's scene rect only changes the area of the scene visible on the viewport, but doesn't affect the size of the view. Note that if you need to set an exact width based on the scene, you have to consider the margins of the viewport (including the QFrame lineWidth and possibly at least an extra pixel due to the scene contents and translation management) so that scrollbars are shown only when really needed.

Comment: That kind of partially got through my problem, but for some reason, when i set the height of the view to the parent's height, some solid scroll bars still appear when there is width to expand to, though the scroll bar doesnt have space to move. Additionally when the widget is initialized, the width is weird and I have to call my resize function again after the widget is added to a window, to fix it....

Comment: I'd suggest you to edit your code and provide a complete [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we could try to understand what's going on there exactly.

Comment: @musicamante I updated the Question. Please take a look

Comment: Sorry but that is not enough. Please update the question with a minimal reproducible example as explained in the link on my previous comment. We must able to copy/paste/run it and test its behavior.

Comment: I have updated the queston with more accurate details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to always keep the default transformation (no scaling), it could make sense to set the view sceneRect using the actual scene rect as a reference.

Note that, since the window could be resized, it's usually better to use a common function to do so, and call it also within the `resizeEvent()`. This also ensures that the view is resized if the vertical scroll bar becomes visible.

```
class canvas(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, size= 'A4', ppi= '72'):
        # ...
        w, h = paperSizes[self.canvasSize][self.ppi]
        self.painter.setSceneRect(0, 0, w, h)
        # ensure that the scene is always aligned on the left, instead of being
        # centered (the default)
        self.view.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        # no need for this here
        # self.view.setSceneRect(0, 0, w, h) 

    def resizeView(self, w, h):
        self.painter.setSceneRect(0, 0, w, h)
        self.adjustView()

    def adjustView(self):
        self.view.setSceneRect(0, 0, self.painter.sceneRect().width() - self.view.frameWidth() * 2, 
            self.painter.sceneRect().height())
        # give the view some time to adjust itself
        QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
        width = self.painter.sceneRect().width() + self.view.frameWidth() * 2
        if self.view.verticalScrollBar().isVisible():
            width += self.style().pixelMetric(QtWidgets.QStyle.PM_ScrollBarExtent)
        self.view.setFixedWidth(width)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.adjustView()
```

Obviously, if you're sure that the view will always show the full width of the scene, you could also completely disable the horizontal scrollbar by setting its [horizontalScrollBarPolicy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#horizontalScrollBarPolicy-prop) to `Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff`.

Comment: But what if I wanted to scale or maybe actually implement  a zoom like feature, how would that work out?

Comment: Additionally, You did not handle the case when width is more than viewport size...
For me, when considering that with min(self.parentWidget().width(), self.painter.sceneRect().width()) + #frame width , doesnt help me out, as the window expands to fit the width of the view itself.... which is strange. and no horizontal scroll bar appear.